# React application showing NaN while the button hasn't been clicked yet

Tags: reactjs

So as I am learning and trying to do simple feedback application, while the user hasn't selected any of the options yet, the Average and Positive Percentage is showing NaN as the values. Why is it so? Am I supposed to use .this? Thank you for any kind of help. I believe it's simple, but couldn't find any solution to it.

```
  console.log({sum})
  console.log({counter})
  const average = sum/counter;
  const positivePercentage = (positive / counter * 100)
  return(
    <div>
      <p>Good {good}</p>
      <p>Neutral {neutral}</p>
      <p>Bad {bad}</p>
      <p>Total Feedbacks: {counter}</p>
      <p>Average: {(Math.round(average*100)/100).toFixed(2)}</p>
      <p>Positive: {(Math.round(positivePercentage*100)/100).toFixed(2)}%</p>
    </div>
  )
}
const Button = ({handleClick, choice}) => {
  return(
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      {choice}
    </button>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  // save clicks of each button to own state
  const [good, setGood] = useState(0)
  const [neutral, setNeutral] = useState(0)
  const [bad, setBad] = useState(0)
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  const [sum, setSum] = useState(0)
  const [positive, setPositive] = useState(0)


  const voteGood = () => {
    return (
      setGood(good+1),
      setCounter(counter+1),
      setSum(sum+1),
      setPositive(positive+1)
     )
    }
  const voteNeutral = () => {
    return(
      setNeutral(neutral+1),
      setCounter(counter+1),
      setSum(sum+0)
    )
  }
  const voteBad = () => {
    return (
      setBad(bad+1),
      setCounter(counter+1),
      setSum(sum-1)
    )

  }
  const resetCounter = () =>{
    return (
      setGood(0),
      setBad(0),
      setNeutral(0),
      setCounter(0),
      setSum(0),
      setPositive(0)
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Division by 0, initial state for `counter` is 0.

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

...

const average = sum/counter;
const positivePercentage = (positive / counter * 100)
```

`NaN` is a falsey value though, so you can "guard" them when rendering by providing a fallback value, i.e. `NaN || 0 // 0`.

```js
const positive = 0;
const counter = 0;

const positivePercentage = (positive / counter * 100);

console.log('positivePercentage', positivePercentage); // NaN

console.log('safe positivePercentage', positivePercentage || 0); // 0
```